# Custom modal background diming in react

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, opacity

I have the following code with me. Please help me how to add opacity or how to dim the background while modal is open.

Here is the [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-http-o2lnd)

Answer (score 0):

Add this `backgroundColor` property to your `Modal` component in line 57:

```
style={{
  display: this.state.display,
  backgroundColor: this.state.modalShow ? "red" : "none"
}}
```

What this does is that when the `modalShow` state is truthy (aka when it's shown) the `backgroundColor` returns `red` and `none` the other way. To dim it you can use `rgba(0,0,0,.2)` instead of `red` obviously

EDIT: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-platform-3e1m1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: this is something I want to achieve click on the launch demo modal you can see the effect https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: Yes, that's what I just answered. Did you have a problem? I'm editing sharing my codesandbox